# How to stop Hex Rays optimizations?

Tags: ida, hexrays, decompiler

I know it's not a bug, but a feature. Hex Rays found that there's a variable which is set to specific value, thus there's no need to display the branches where the code will never be run, so it warns me about the optimizations:

```
conditional instruction was optimized away because of '%var_8.1==0'
```

Is there any way to make it show all the code branches and stop optimizing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try marking the variable as [volatile](https://hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/manual/tricks.shtml#01)

Comment: I can't, it was also optimized :)

Comment: @AntonKukoba maybe try doing it on the stack frame variable (Ctrl-K)

Comment: I tried it too, it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help other people face with this problem in the future.
The answer is: make all related-variables `volatile`. See the image bellow:
[image: hexrays optimization]

Either `code_compress_magic` or `Signature` must be set as a `volatile` type. This will make Hexrays decompiler happy.